# $f(x)=\arctan(x)-\ln(x)$, find the interval where f(x)=0 has 1 solution

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=\arctan(x)-\ln(x)$ , find the interval where $f(x)=0$ has $1$ real solution

a) $(1,e)$

b) $(e,e^2)$

c) $(e^2, ∞)$

d) $(0,1)$

I know that when a function is continuous, if $f(c)=0$ with $c\in (a,b)$ then $f(a)\times f(b)<0$

My problem here is the fact that I do not know the values of $\arctan(e)$ and/or $\arctan(e^2)$

Comment: If you only care about whether $f(x)$ is positive, negative or zero, can you tell whether $\arctan(e)$ is bigger than, smaller than or equal to $\ln(e)=1$? Same for $\arctan(e^2)$.

Comment: You do know some values of $\arctan$, like $\arctan(1)$, $\arctan(\sqrt{3})$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan(x)$. It's not always true that if $f$ is continuous, $f(c)=0$, and $c \in (a,b)$ then $f(a) \cdot f(b)<0$ (consider $f(x)=x^2, a=-1, b=1, c=0$). What is true is that if $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and $f(a) \cdot f(b)<0$ then there must be at least one value $c$ with $f(c)=0$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the different ways we can take advantage of monotonicity?

Comment: @A.M. Based on the answer arctan(e) is bigger than ln(e)
as for $arctan(e^2)$ it must be smaller than $ln(e^2)$ .
If I didn't know the answer I couldn't tell you.

Comment: @StephenDonovan I am somewhat familiar , any solution , hint or answer you could give me would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, although your original claim that if $f(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (a,b)$ then $f(a) \cdot f(b) < 0$ is false as pointed out in the comments, we can justify a similar statement via other means.

Consider the derivative of our function: $f'(x) = \frac1{1+x^2} - \frac1x = \frac{-x^2 + x - 1}{x^3 + x}.$ Note that the denominator is positive for all positive $x$ (which is to say over the entire domain of $f$) and that the numerator can be rewritten as $-(x - \frac12)^2 - \frac34,$ which is negative for all real $x$. So, for all $x > 0,$ we have $f'(x) < 0.$

Because of this, for any $b > a > 0,$ because we can say that $f(b) - f(a) = \int_a^b f'(x) dx,$ and $f'(x) < 0 \Rightarrow \int_a^b f'(x) dx < 0,$ we have that $f(b) < f(a).$ This is to say that our function $f$ is *monotonically decreasing.*

Now suppose that there exist some $x_1 \neq x_2$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = 0.$ If $x_1 > x_2,$ then by our argument so far we must have $f(x_1) < f(x_2),$ but it is not true that $0 < 0.$ Similarly, if $x_2 > x_1$ then $f(x_2) < f(x_1)$ and $0 < 0.$ This leads to a contradiction, and we have that there cannot be two distinct zeroes.

*Now* we can say that there exists exactly one zero in the interval $(a,b)$ if and only if $f(a) > 0$ (or $a = 0$) and $f(b) < 0.$ The forward implication is true because if $f(c) = 0$ and $a  < c,$ then by monotonicity we have $f(a) > f(c) = 0,$ and if $b > c$ then we have $f(b) < f(c) = 0.$ The implication in the other direction comes from the Intermediate Value Theorem and the uniqueness of the zero.

---

Now that we've established that, we've caught back up to where you were, which is testing the different points.

$f(1)$ is easy because we know the values exactly: $\arctan(1) - \ln(1) = \frac\pi4 - 0 = \frac\pi4 > 0.$

$f(e)$ is, as you pointed out, much trickier, but we can take advantage of monotonicity again to tackle it, this time using the monotonicity of $\arctan(x)$. Recall that the derivative of $\arctan(x)$ is $\frac1{1+x^2},$ which is positive for all real $x.$ By a similar argument as before, this means that if $b > a,$ then $\arctan(b) > \arctan(a).$ So, since $e > \sqrt{3},$ we have $\arctan(e) > \arctan(\sqrt{3}) = \frac\pi3 > 1,$ so $f(e) = \arctan(e) - 1 > 0.$ So, there are no zeroes in the interval $(1, e).$

$f(e^2)$ is actually a bit easier to deal with: because $-\frac\pi2 < \arctan(x) < \frac\pi2$ for all real $x,$ we know that $\arctan(e^2) < \frac\pi2 < 2,$ so $f(e^2) = \arctan(e^2) - 2 < 0.$

By our earlier argument, we can now conclude that there exists exactly one zero in the interval $(e, e^2),$ and the correct option is $\boxed{\text{(b).}}$

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much , this helped a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)